# Get JavaFx Tab Content

Tags: java, javafx

I got a little problem with the JavaFx Tabs. I am triing to examine the content of a tab and assign it to a variable, but I am not quite sure how to do this. I tried to cast it but that didn't take me anywhere, so here I am now.

```
//e.g.
Tab tab = new Tab();
tab.setContent(new TextArea());

TextArea tArea = tab.getContent(); // <- that's where I struggle
```

I would be very happy if you could help me out and even if you can't, 
I wish you a very nice day. :)

Comment: Casting is the way to do this (assuming you can't just assign the text area to a variable when you create it), so can you [edit] your question and show how you tried to do that? (Also fix the obvious typo on the last line.)